# How to get Meteor app to use python script to write to database?

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, meteor

I want a python script to interact with my Meteor app's database, but I'm not sure how to get the two to talk to each other. How do I get the script to write directly to the mongodb database on the server?

Thanks

Comment: can you share your `MONGO_URL` syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You should try pymongo, after install it with pip:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
db = client.test_database
collection = db.test_collection
```

Then you can use collection.insert(document) to write directly to the mongodb database, you can find more information [here](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html).

Comment: when trying to connect to the client I'm getting a ConnectionFailure errno 61

Comment: You have to make sure mongodb is started and running